# I have raspberrypi 4 board, after putting sd card only the pwr led is glowing not act led. And also the red led is not bright as usual

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

I tried booting with different SD cards but the problem is same , os was not booting and the pwr led was glowing with low intensity.

Can you give me any solution to overcome this issue Please!

Comment: [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

Comment: Sounds like the Pi is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably an undervoltage from your power supply or something with the image on the sd card.
Use raspberry pi imager(https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/) and try a headless image to see if it boots first.